# How to get the text from a textarea jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am trying to get the user text entered in a text area in a confirmation dialog.
Any ideas how?

`alert ($('#optionalmessage').text());` doesn't seem to do it.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3FyF9/1/)

```
$(doument).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function (event) {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Send it ": function () {
                alert ($('#optionalmessage').text());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Also I need to create some more space for this textarea (more than it currently has in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FyF9/1/) ) but using

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
```

it almost disappears ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/3FyF9/7/)

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#click").click(function (event) {

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 375,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function () {

                     alert ($('#optionalmessage').val());
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
alert ($('#optionalmessage').val());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/3FyF9/6/)